# creating an observable collection from XML file read

Tags: xml, windows-phone-8, observablecollection

I have an xml file like this

```
<Root>
  <Day id="Monday">
    <subject name="Software Testing" session="2010" group="Alpha" teacher="Tasawar Khan" classroom="Class Room 1" time="8:30">

    </subject>
  </Day>
  <Day id="Tuesday">
    <subject name="Digital Image Processing" session="2011" group="Alpha" teacher="Ali Javed" classroom="Class Room 2" time="11:30">

    </subject>

  </Day>
  <Day id="Wednesday">
    <subject name="Digital Image Processing" session="2011" group="Alpha" teacher="Ali Javed" classroom="Class Room 2" time="11:30">

    </subject>
  </Day>
  <Day id="Thursday">
    <subject name="Digital Image Processing" session="2011" group="Alpha" teacher="Ali Javed" classroom="Class Room 2" time="11:30">

    </subject>
  </Day>
  <Day id="Friday">
    <subject name="Digital Image Processing" session="2011" group="Alpha" teacher="Ali Javed" classroom="Class Room 2" time="11:30">

    </subject>
  </Day>

</Root>
```

I am reading and binding this file to a ListBox as follows

```
string TeachersXMLPath = "Teachers.xml";
            XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load(TeachersXMLPath);

           var data = (from query in loadedData.Descendants("Day").Descendants("subject")

                       select new TimeTable
                       {
                           Teacher = (string)query.Attribute("teacher").Value,
                           Subject = (string)query.Attribute("name"),
                           Session = (string)query.Attribute("session"),
                           Group = (string)query.Attribute("group")
                       });

            listBox.ItemsSource = data;
```

Here is my TimeTable class:

```
public class TimeTable
{
    string teacher;
    string subject;
    string session;
    string group;
    string time;
    string classroom;

    //Teacher Property

    public string Teacher
    {
        get{ return teacher;        }
        set{ teacher = value;        }
    }
    //Subject Property

    public string Subject
    {
        get { return subject; }
        set { subject = value; }
    }
    //Session Propert

    public string Session
    {
        get { return session; }
        set { session = value; }
    }
    //Group Property

    public string Group
    {
        get { return group; }
        set { group = value; }
    }
    //Time Property

    public string Time
    {
        get { return time; }
        set { time = value; }
    }

    public string Location
    {
        get { return classroom; }
        set { classroom = value; }
    }


}
```

And here is my ListBox

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Hold="teacher_detail_Hold" Margin="0,12,0,12">

                <Grid x:Name="LayoutList2" Background="BurlyWood">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Teacher}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock Name="subjectName" Text="{Binding Subject}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Session}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Group}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                                <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                        Click="delete_record"
                                        BorderThickness="0">
                                    <Image Source="/Images/appbar.delete.rest.png"
                                           Width="75"
                                           Height="75"/>
                                </Button>
                            </Grid>

            </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

It works good when displaying data.

**What I want is to bind ObservableCollection to ListBox** so I would also be able to delete the selected item from list, when delete button clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `ViewModel` class.
This `ViewModel` class should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.
Declare a `ObservableCollection` of `TimeTable` class.
Set the `DataContext` of your ListBox to be the `ViewModel`.
Set the `ItemsSource` of the ListBox to be the `ObservableCollection`.

Your ViewModel will look like this:

```
public class SomeViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged{

 private ObservableCollection<TimeTable> _timeTableCollection;

 public ObservableCollection<TimeTable> TimeTableCollection{
   get{
     return _timeTableCollection; 
    }
   set{     
     _timeTableCollection = value;
onPropertyChanged(this, "TimeTableCollection"); 
   }
 }




// Declare the PropertyChanged event
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // OnPropertyChanged will raise the PropertyChanged event passing the
    // source property that is being updated.
    private void onPropertyChanged(object sender, string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(sender, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

}
```